# I have an issue with Admob, Autolayout and adding constraints.

Tags: ios, xcode4.5

I have successfully added admob into my project as a secondary source of advertising.

I then wanted the admob banner to always remain at the bottom of the screen (regardless of the iphone used)- simple enough. Unfortunately, I now have a very odd problem. Both iAd AND Admobs banners now somehow appear underneath the toolbar at the bottom of the screen.

I literally dont understand this - first of all as the toolbar is set to opaque (yet you can see the advert through it (just)) - second why is my iAd banner suddenly doing the same thing?!

Here is the code I'm currently running. Any input would be greatly appreciated!

```
-(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error {

[UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOff" context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:2];
[banner setAlpha:0];
[UIView commitAnimations];

admobBannerView = [[GADBannerView alloc]
                    initWithFrame:CGRectMake (0.0,0.0,
                                              GAD_SIZE_320x50.width,
                                              GAD_SIZE_320x50.height)];
self.admobBannerView.adUnitID = @"X";
self.admobBannerView.rootViewController = self;
self.admobBannerView.delegate = self;

[self.view addSubview:self.admobBannerView];

[self.view addConstraint:
 [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.admobBannerView
                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                 toItem:self.view
                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                             multiplier:1.0
                               constant:0]];

self.admobBannerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;


GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
request.testDevices = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"X", nil];

[self.admobBannerView loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some reading around storyboards and tool bars in particular I finally worked out what I was doing wrong.

As my admob banner was constrained to the bottom of the view it was created in - I had set the toolbar to opaque in the navigation controller but not in the actual view controller I was running the advert in. Although you can apparently only have ONE type of toolbar per application (set in the navigation controller), the storyboard allows you to chop and change between view controllers (even if this isn't translated into the application build). This seems stupid to me.

This is what caused the banner to be created under the translucent toolbar.